# Why a call to a php function with jquery returns the PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this php file

```
    if(isset($_GET['fn']))
    {
    if($_GET['fn']=='generarxml')
    generarxml();
    else 
    exit;
    }


    function generarxml()
    {
            alert("si jalo");
    }
```

and when i want to call the "generarxml" function, it returns me the whole code, instead of an answer or the alert. The way im calling it is this.

```
    function test()
            {
            $.ajax({
                                            url: "/include/generaxml.php?fn=generarxml",
                                            type: 'post',
                                            data: {},
                                            success: function(output){
                                                 alert (output);
                                            }
                                      });
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like your server, if any, doesn't process PHP

Comment: is the php code wrapped in php tags?

Comment: I don't think `alert()` in PHP is going to do what you think it would do...

Comment: Im on localhost with wamp, idk if that is a problem, the php code isnt wrapped, and what do alert then? sorry for being so n00b with this XC

Comment: @PepoLazcano Than that's your problem. You need to wrap the code in php tags <?php // your code here ?> so it can be processed as PHP code. Your's is just being parsed as plain html characters or text

Comment: Thanks! i thought that was automatic fot the "file.PHP", but it isnt after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like either you haven't wrapped your PHP code around `<?php ?>` tags or the web server is not configured to pass PHP code to the PHP engine.
Also, the `alert()` does not exist in PHP, either use `echo` or `print`.

Here's an example of how your code should look like:

```
<?php
function generarxml() {
    echo "si jalo";
}

if(isset($_GET['fn']) && $_GET['fn'] == "generarxml") {
    generarxml();
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the >?p ?> thing, and the way you reestructured my poor code, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets get clear on a few things:

1. Do you have a server running on your machine that compiles php? Take a look at WAMP/XAMP if you don't have one, these a quite popular
2. Where are you running/calling the code? How do you get the error?
3. Where do you define alert() function? It looks like you're trying to use javascript code inside php - it doesnt work as expected, because php is server side language (compiled on the server), while javascript is clien side (compiled on the user machine)

And finally - what is your goal, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, i have:D i have wamp actually, im running it on phprunner, i didnt got the error, i just had to figure it out cuz this software dont tell me if im wrong jahjha, and alert, i was confused by javascript thing! my mid got confused and all, sorry about that, but the answer above help with the problem, and, what im trying to do? im trying to create XML files with a .php external file that is called when i press a button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing some of your javascript code with the PHP code (two different languages)

Try altering your php file so that it either returns or echoes the answer you need:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['fn']))
{
    if($_GET['fn']=='generarxml')
       return generarxml();
    else 
       return false;
}


function generarxml()
{
   return ("si jalo");
}

?>
```

If that doesn't work i would suggest you consider *A. Wolff*'s comment that your server might not be processing your php files correctly.

Comment: Hey, thanks! sory for the late reply, i tried some of the above answers and they work, but thabks!